# Access instance variables of properties inherited from protocols

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, protocols, instance-variables

I have created a simple protocol which enforces an `NSString` property on conforming classes:

```
@protocol CPTSettingViewModel <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic) NSString *titleText;

@end
```

When I create a class which conforms to this protocol, Xcode suggests that I synthsize the property:

```
@synthesize titleText;
```

My issue is that when I then try to reference this property's instance variable in my initialiser, I receive the error:

> Use of undeclared identifier '_titleText'; did you mean 'titleText'?

How can I access instance variables of properties inherited from protocols rather than ending up with something like this where I use the property itself?

```
- (instancetype)initWithTitleText:(NSString *)titleText selectionText:(NSString *)selectionText {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.titleText = titleText;
        _selectionText = selectionText;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: i think you want pass titleText to one VC to other VC right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default instance variable name when you use `@synthesize` is the name of the property itself -- `titleText` in this case.  The default auto-synthesis (which does not work due to the property being in the protocol) will insert the equivalent to `@synthesize titleText = _titleText`, which is how the underscores become the usual name in that case.  I believe you can just specify the name with the underscore (i.e. `@synthesize titleText = _titleText`) to have the instance variable name then match what you are expecting.